# Couchbase: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.getView

Tags: java, couchbase, nosuchmethoderror

Using Couchbase (client) and Java.

Basically, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.getView(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/couchbase/client/protocol/views/View;
```

on this line:

```
View view = client.getView(DESIGN_DOC, VIEW_NAME);
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? The "autocomplete" option does give me this function, so I don't see how it can give me a "NoSuchMethodError" then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using the couchbase-client-1.1.0 library.
1.4.x didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there must be something else happening, as that's still there and used by a lot of people in 1.4.x.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the place you're running the program is using a different set of jars than the place you're developing/compiling the program.  This can also happen if you do incremental builds.  Try to clean and rebuild the project and/or verify the jar you're using is the same at runtime from compile time.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out eventually!

I was using the wrong library version. This don't make sense though since the function itself was in the other (newer) versions as well, but it worked when I went back to older versions.
#logic